# css sudden loss of second opposite floated element?

Tags: css, layout, document, floating

I have this very simple code with one container element and two internal elements h1 and h2 both floated in opposite directions. However when I apply that second element is missing eventhough I set bellow the empty paragraph tag with the property clear:both just to be certain that parent-collapse isn't going to happen. However second element still seems to be missing? Here is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>first heading</h1>
        <h2>second heading</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is my css code:

```
body, div, h1, h2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
body{
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;
}

#container{
        background:navy;

}
#container h1{
    background:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;

    }
#container h2{
    background:yellow;
    width:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:right;
}
p{
    clear:both;
}
```

Please any help would be time-savior?

Comment: Also for anyone I apologize for putting two times width:200px on the #container h2, so I immediately replaced that to height:200px but still doesn't want to work anyway?

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. Sorry and thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2x `width:200px;` style definitions in `#container h2`. Change it to `height` and everything will start working :)

Comment: Is your browser window more than 960px wide? Your body tag has `width: 960px`, so if your browser is narrow, it will not show your `float: right` element.

Answer (score 1):

You have written width twice instead of height. Please replace it as following.

```
#container h1{
    background:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;

    }
#container h2{
    background:yellow;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
}
```

Here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/s9C6D/

[image: Snap from fiddle]

Answer (score 0):

maximgladkov was right I think..?

here is what he suggested:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjefh